# Helper not loading in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, helper

Here is my simple controller:

```
public function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
}


public function view($page = "index")
{

    if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/truelove_view/'.$page.'.php'))
    {
        // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
        show_404();
    } 

        $this->load->view('truelove_view/templates/header.php');
        $this->load->view('truelove_view/'.$page);   
        $this->load->view('truelove_view/templates/footer.php');
```

When I include $this->load->helper('url'); in view() the code works, but when I include it in the constructor as above then it doesn't. It also works if I autoload url helper.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code provided, you have `public function _construct()` , but it should be `public function __construct()`. You need to add the double underscore `__`

Comment: Awesome, thank you. It was the single underscore. Im using a new IDE and some characters look different.

Comment: Codelobster, swtiched from notepad++

Comment: Never tried it, but I heard of it. I recommend Netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Load your helper using an array:

```
$this->load->helper( array('url') );
```